# Where is my "xubuntu desktop"?

Tags: thunar

I have been using Xubuntu 14.04 for some weeks now. Today I did some kind of "hard shutdown" - I "ejected" an USB stick and that took ages; and as I didn't care about the stick's content; I ran "shutdown"; but the whole system hung; so I finally pressed the power button on my laptop.

Now my Xubuntu comes up; I can login; all applications behave normally; but it seems that something happened to "thunar" and/or my desktop. All the icons are gone (although I have files in my Desktop directory); and right click on the desktop does not start the typical menu. I already re-installed all thunar related packages.

There are no errors in the `.xsession-errors`; any idea how to fix this; or where to look for log files?

Answer (score 1):

I ran `xfdesktop` on the command line, and the desktop behavior came back. But this only helped for the current session (xfdesktop would not start automatically after logging out and in again).

Then, when logged out, I did `mv .cache/sessions ~/`; then logged in; and voila, everything worked fine again. After I saw that, I simply deleted the `sessions` directory which I had moved to `~` before. (I always move config stuff away to check out what happens without it; it is a rather bad idea to just delete things for experiments)